# DatePicker disable error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, office365, office-ui-fabric

I want to create a component, which consists of [Datepicker](https://dev.office.com/fabric#/components/datepicker) and [ChoiceGroup](https://dev.office.com/fabric#/components/choicegroup) using ReactJs and office365. On first render datepicker must be disabled, and when we choose custom radio button in ChoiceGroup it must be enabled.Piece of code:

```
<div>
                    <ChoiceGroup
                        defaultSelectedKey='all'
                        onChange={ this._onChange }
                        label='Date'
                        options={ [
                            {
                                key: 'all',
                                text: 'All'
                            },
                            {
                                key: 'thisWeek',
                                text: 'This week',
                            },
                            {
                                key: 'lastWeek',
                                text: 'Last week',
                            },
                            {
                                key: 'thisMonth',
                                text: 'This month',
                            },
                            {
                                key: 'custom',
                                text: 'Custom',
                            }
                        ] }

                    />

                            <DatePicker
                                label='label'
                                isRequired={ false }
                                disabled={ pickerDisabled }
                                strings={ strings }
                                allowTextInput={ false }
                                value={ value }
                            />

                </div>
```

picker has `disabled` param and I wanted to change it in ChoiceGrou method:

```
onChange = (ev, option) => {
        console.dir(option);
        if(option.key === 'custom') {
            this.setState({
                pickerDisabled: false
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                pickerDisabled: true
            })
        }
    }
```

This method works and  changes parameter, but datepicker component's disable doesnt change. it remains the same and I got error in console when I click any radio button:

```
Exception in DatePicker.componentWillReceiveProps(): TypeError: date1.getFullYear is not a function
```

What can be the reason of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are passing an invalid `value` to the `DatePicker` component, my guess (without more context/info) is that `value` is `null`/`undefined` by default and `DatePicker` defaults to the current day, but the `value` is being set by the radio buttons and it's a not a valid value (based on the error, it looks like `DatePicker` is expecting a `Date` object (it's trying to call `getFullYear()` on it), but `value` is a string).

Check the `DatePicker` component's documentation for what it expects in its `value` prop and update accordingly.

Comment: you are right I put new Date() to value and it works,thank you